# Redirect Intel GPU Video output to NVIDIA GPU

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, intel, gpu

I have a Razer Blade 2019. It has three video output ports (DP over USB-C, mDP and HDMI) but all three are directly connected with the NVIDIA GPU (RTX 2080). I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I would like to use the iGPU to manage the Xorg session and the screens, allowing the NVIDIA GPU to be used exclusively for deep learning.
I couldn't find a way of redirecting the Intel GPU output to some of this outputs, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a driver installed that uses the Nvidia card only for specific apps, likewise the same driver is also able to uses the Intel iGPU in low-powered situations, and to convert to using the Nvidia card when required like you would expect works without configuration in a Windows or Mac device. This is part of the [Nvidia Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) project.

Nvidia provides this driver, as long as you have a device that has both an Intel iGPU and a Nvidia dGPU (if you do, which you do, you have what is known as an Optimus-ready system)

Ubuntu users specifically have the Nvidia Prime driver which is the Nvidia-supported way of having iGPU-dGPU switching functionality. Follow [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04) to install the drivers and pre-requisite packages.

The feature with Nvidia Prime that specifically allows for switching is known as Prime Offloading, you can invoke it manually [via the command line](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=301410). 19.10 users can also download a [lovely applet](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/09/nvidia-optimus-linux-switching-applet) to do the same

Bonus fact: Though Nvidia Prime is the officially supported way of getting the iGPU and dGPU working together to optimize on power, there have been other drivers around before Nvidia Prime that provided this same functionality. Allegedly the nvidia-xrun driver provides the best performance in gaming according to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/6ftq10/the_ultimate_guide_to_setting_up_nvidia_optimus/). It could be worth considering if gaming on the Linux is something you are interested in.